# Can the site association bonus be rewarded more than once?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

Is it actually possible?

I was reading the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
 and saw:

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account

Ok, what if I achieve on one and then having rep between 100 and 200 on another I reach again 200 on the second, do I get the bonus again?

Comment: Only once per site can you receive an association bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't receive it more than once on the same site.  You'll always receive it for every new site in the network that you register for, but you won't be able to get more than 100 reputation in this way for any given site.

It's also worth noting that this 100 rep doesn't count towards answering a protected post, as you haven't *earned* any reputation on that site yet.